# ProgressBar dynamically Color Android

Tags: android, listview, colors

I have a Listview populated by data taken from the database, for each record I entered a progreesbar. Fetch from the database and check the color of the TextView background and I would like to assign it to a ProgressBar. How can I do? In the method getView () I have added a ProgressBar.

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        tvC.setBackgroundColor(d.colore);//I would also assign color to the ProgressBar
 final ProgressBar mProgress;
             mProgress = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progress_e);
             mProgress.setMax(100);
             final float numero_float = (float) value;
                // run progress
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                         int progressStatus = 0;

                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                        public void run() {
                            while (progressStatus < numero_float) {
                                progressStatus += 1;
                                // Update the progress bar and display the current value 
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        mProgress.setProgress(progressStatus);

                                    }
                                });
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(40);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
...
...
```

Comment: getPrograssDrawable() of your ProgressBar and replace the layer with id == android.id.progress with your custom ClipDrawable that clips desired color

Comment: sorry, I did not understand. Can you give me an example? thanks

Comment: get progress drawable first, cast it to LayerDrawable and replace layer with id android.R.id.progress with your custom ClipDrawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ColorMatrixColorFilter to change the color of the progressbar dynamically

```
    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) viewFindById(...);
    int color = Color.RED;  // for example..but use your own color value here
    float[] progressMatrix = {
            0, 0, 0, 0, Color.red(color), //red
            0, 0, 0, 0, Color.blue(color), //blue
            0, 0, 0, 0, Color.green(color), //green
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0  //alpha
    };
    progressMaskColorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(progressMatrix));
    progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(progressMaskColorFilter);
```

If you want to color the thumb of a seekbar as well, do the above and then follow up with this:

```
    progressBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(scrubberMaskColorFilter);
```

The ColorMatrix will preserve the alpha values in the image but replace the color with your own color.